# Running command with resource as argument

Tags: java, process, jar, command, arguments

<strike>I am running a jar file on a different path on the system programmatically. One of the arguments needed is the path to a file, and the file is in my jar file. How can I pass the file (script.ospt) as an argument for another java application?</strike>

Current code:

```
    Process ps = null;
    try {
        ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-jar",engine.getAbsolutePath(), script3.getAbsolutePath()});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ps.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EDIT: More explanation:

I have a command I would like to run from java, using Runtime.getRuntime().exec().
The command I am running requires one argument: the path to a file. If the file is in the same package as my main class, how can I use the file in my program as an argument for the command?

Comment: you can pass filename as a string .create a file from it

Comment: Can I have an example for how to get a file from this.getClass().getResource()?

Comment: do you want to open jar file from another java program passing a file ?am i correct?not so clear may u add some details

Comment: @FastSnail I have now explained a bit further.